# converting a C to MIPS

Tags: c, for-loop, mips

I'm trying to make this C code translated directly to mips, without modifying any instructions:

```
  for (i=0; i<128; i++)

           { a[i] = b[i] - c[i] + 5; }
```

I'm just trying to understand some things. Here what I have so far

```
add $t4, $zero, $zero    # I1 i is initialized to 0, $t4 = 0
Loop:
add $t5, $t4, $t1        # I2 temp reg $t5 = address of b[i]
lw $t6, 0($t5)          # I3 temp reg $t6 = b[i]
add $t5, $t4, $t2        # I4 temp reg $t5 = address of c[i]
lw $t7, 0($t5)          # I5 temp reg $t7 = c[i] + 5
sub $t6, $t6, $t7        # I6 temp reg $t6 = b[i] - c[i] + 5
add $t5, $t4, $t0        # I7 temp reg $t5 = address of a[i]
sw $t6, 0($t5)          # I8 a[i] = b[i] - c[i] + 5 
addi $t4, $t4, 4            # I9 i = i + 1
slti $t5, $t4, 256      # I10 $t5 = 1 if $t4 < 128, i.e. i < 10
bne $t5, $zero, Loop        # I11 go to Loop if $t4 < 128
exit:
```

I not sure if I need to load 5 by itself or if its ok the way that I have it where it loads with c[i]? Any tips would be helpful since I'm still trying to learn mips. Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual question? Hint: question should normally have a question mark at the end, especially in a QA site like this :-)

Comment: I added a question mark but let me know if you need more of an explanation

Answer (score 1):

`5` is a constant number here. Doing something like `lw $t7, 0($t5)` will not not load `$t7` with `5` unless the address (word to be exact) zero offsets from `$t5` has a `5` in it (and you have not stored `5` at the said location in your code).

If you want to add the constant `5` to a register (say `$t0`) why not do `addi $t0, 5`?

Comment: So i would  `addi $t0, 5` in my code and than a `lw` to load it?

Comment: The instruction `lw $t7,  0($t5)` goes to zero offsets / bytes ahead of the number (which should be a valid address) contained in `$t5` and loads the  `word` at that address in `$t7` - that is not what you want. You want to add `5` to the register which has the value of `c[i]`, to do that you need to use `addi`. HTH.